# Hide datePicker when tapping on another cell?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm playing around with date pickers by following "App Development with Swift" by Apple. At chapter 4.9, page 700.

What I can't figure out is how to make my date pickers hide when I select another cell that's not one of the two date pickers. They hide fine if you click on them but I'd like to be able to hide them by selecting any other cell  if my view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {

    case (checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.row - 1):

        if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = false
        } else if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = true
        } else {
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = true
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    case (checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.row - 1):

        if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
        } else if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
            isCheckInDatePickerShown = false
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = true
        } else {
            isCheckOutDatePickerShown = true
        }

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()

    default:
        break
        }
```

I'm new to the whole thing and just want to start wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can force this behaviour on your default case, meaning that if the tapped cell isn't check-in or checkout, picker hides.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

  switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {

  case (checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkInDatePickerCellIndexPath.row - 1):

     if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
         isCheckInDatePickerShown = false
     } else if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
         isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
         isCheckInDatePickerShown = true
     } else {
         isCheckInDatePickerShown = true
     }

     tableView.beginUpdates()
     tableView.endUpdates()

  case (checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.section, checkOutDatePickerCellIndexPath.row - 1):

     if isCheckOutDatePickerShown {
         isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
     } else if isCheckInDatePickerShown {
         isCheckInDatePickerShown = false
         isCheckOutDatePickerShown = true
     } else {
         isCheckOutDatePickerShown = true
     }

     tableView.beginUpdates()
     tableView.endUpdates()

  default:

     isCheckOutDatePickerShown = false
     isCheckInDatePickerShown = false

     tableView.beginUpdates()
     tableView.endUpdates()

     break
 }
}
```

Comment: That’s the first thing I tried as well but doesn’t seem to work. Doesn’t change the behavior at all actually.

Comment: Have you considered changing the switch for an if?